# Динамическое изменение background

Tags: jquery, css

Доброе время суток. Интересует возможность динамической смены (без перезагрузки страницы) фона страниц сайта (background или background-image). Если правильно понимаю, то нужно использовать jQuery. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может нужно что-то наподобие этого: [jQuery background image tweening plugin](http://soxer.mutsu.org/offshots/bgImageTween)?

Comment: Спасибо, мне это больше подходит

Answer (score 2):

Можно и с помощью jQuery.

```
$('selector').css('background-image','url(path_to_image/img.jpg)');
```

[Смотреть пример тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/DSngA/1/).